# for loop getting skipped in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, skip

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript guessing game, and my for loop keeps getting skipped! Here is the part of my code that is getting skipped:

```
for (i = 0; i === tries; i += 1) {
    isSkipped = false;
    var guessedNumber = prompt("Guess your number now.");

    console.log("User guessed number " + guessedNumber);

    //check if number is correct
    if (guessedNumber === numberToGuess) {
        confirm("Hooray, you have guessed the number!");
        break;
    } else if (guessedNumber > numberToGuess) {
        confirm("A little too high...");
    } else {
        confirm("A little too low...");
    }
}
```

and here is the full code:

```
//declaring variables
var numberToGuess;
var tries;
var i;
var isSkipped = true;

var confirmPlay = confirm("Are you ready to play lobuo's guessing game? The number for you to guess will be a number ranging from 1 to 25."); //does the user want to play?

if (confirmPlay === true) {
    console.log("User wants to play");
} else {
    window.location = "http://lobuo.github.io/pages/experiments.html";
} //if user wants to play, let them play, else go to website homepage

numberToGuess = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1); //sets computer-generated number

tries = prompt("How many tries would you like?"); //gets amount of tries
tries = Math.floor(tries); //converts amount of tries to integer from string

for (i = 0; i === tries; i += 1) {
    isSkipped = false;
    var guessedNumber = prompt("Guess your number now.");

    console.log("User guessed number " + guessedNumber);

    //check if number is correct
    if (guessedNumber === numberToGuess) {
        confirm("Hooray, you have guessed the number!");
        break;
    } else if (guessedNumber > numberToGuess) {
        confirm("A little too high...");
    } else {
        confirm("A little too low...");
    }
}

if (isSkipped === true) {
    console.log("Oh no! The for loop has been skipped!");
}
```

If you need any further details, just ask.

Comment: What is this for `i += 0`???

Comment: oops... I fixed that, but still nothing... It was supposed to be i += 1

Comment: Simply use i++; besides `i === tries` is not well iterated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
for (i = 0; i === tries; i += 0) {
```

the loop repeats as long as the condition `i === tries` is true. If `tries` is 3, for instance, this condition is not true on the first iteration, and the loop ends immediately.

You should write:

```
for (i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the for be like this?:

```
for (i = 0; i < tries; i += 1) {
```

Comment: You might want to explain what's the difference between the two, and provide the edited code.

Comment: oops... didnt notice you did i < tries. That fixed it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to use `parseInt()` function on user's input.

```
 var guessedNumber = parseInt(prompt("Guess your number now."), 10);
```

instead of

```
var guessedNumber = prompt("Guess your number now.");
```

Comment: why downvote as he checked for types also `guessedNumber === numberToGuess`?

Comment: @SumanBogati Because the type does not matter since it would be a Number no matter what after `Math.floor`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: the OP doesn't do `Math.floor` on `guessedNumber`, but he does so on `tries`. Because `guessedNumber` is a string while `numberToGuess` is a number, it will never successfully complete.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Oh I see it now. One more reason to use `==` it seems!

Comment: yeah how can be succeed 'string' === number.